# Is it possible to use this small floating notification with Phonegap?

Tags: cordova, android-notifications

I don't know exactly the name of it, so it's hard to find. Android have that small messages that popup over all applications and fade out after few seconds. It's not alert or push notification. Here is one screenshot for example:

http://postimg.org/image/w5a3w015n/

So, is it possible to send that kind of notifications with phonegap? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe [toast](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin) is what youre asking about?

Comment: Exatly! Now I have a name to look for. Thx.